# Как организовать портативную (переносную, мобильную) среду для разработки?

Tags: настройка, виртуальная-машина

Недавно я переустановил ОС на рабочем компе и мне пришлось заново устанавливать все IDE, фотошопы, сервисы, ноды и тд. Затем все это настраивать, докачивать плагины, понять что ты не помнишь где найти лицензионные ключи и тд

Какими средствами можно избежать всех этих установок и настроек при смене ОС или машины?

- Знаю про докер, но с его помощью можно настроить только среду выполнения написанных программ.
- Знаю про виртуальные машины (просто знаю что они есть). Думал попробовать с них. Если кто имеет опыт - подскажите варианты виртуальных машин, плз. Желательно, чтобы при работе в них не было сильных потерь производительности, например, при работе в фотошопе.
- Если есть еще варианты - очень интересно узнать.

Comment: https://evgeniypopov.com/blog/sozdanie-obraza-s-nastroennoj-windows-10-cherez-aomei-backupper.html (первая ссылка в гугле)

Answer (score 1):

Ну под Windows, в пользовательском сегменте, выбор виртуалок не особо большой -- VMWare и VirtualBox. Ничего особо сложного и страшного в виртуалках нет, так что можете попробовать.